# How to swap every 2 value in a variable using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, swap

How can I swap every 2 values in a variable by using batch scripting?

For example:

```
CVDF1234 ---> VCFD2143
```

I already have set an initial value into a variable of batch script.

```
@echo off
set "sValue=CVDF1234"
...
...
echo newsValue
```

What is the missing steps I should fill in?

***I am using Windows 10 64-bits OS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some higher purpose to this? Knowing that might make a better solution possible.

Comment: @AndrewMorton fyi, VCFD2143 is the ultimate result to get. But the result what I get now is this (CVDF1234). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler can this work on  old-style batch files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @TessellatingHeckler can this work on old-style batch files ?

If you have Windows 10, you have PowerShell, so that depends what you mean:

```
set sValue=CVDF1234
for /f "usebackq" %%r in (`powershell "'%sValue%' -replace '(.)(.)','$2$1'"`) do (
    set newsValue=%%r )
echo %newsValue%
```

Comment: PowerShell is available by default since Vista

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "sValue=CVDF1234"
CALL :swap2 svalue newsvalue
ECHO %svalue%
ECHO %newsvalue%
GOTO :EOF

:: swap each 2 characters in %1 to %2

:swap2
setlocal
CALL SET "$1=%%%1%%"
SET "$2="
:Swap2L
SET "$2=%$2%%$1:~1,1%%$1:~0,1%"
SET "$1=%$1:~2%"
IF DEFINED $1 GOTO swap2L
endlocal&SET "%2=%$2%"
GOTO :eof
```

As an exercise - quite what use it might bee, IDK.

provide the original variable name and the receiving variable name as the two parameters, and simply `call` the routine `:swap2`

This establishes $1 and $2 as temporary variables (the setlocal/endlocal bracket makes them temporary) - the `call` sets $1 to the contents of the first variable, it's then simply a matter of building `$2` from the first 2 characters of that string in reverse order, lopping the first 2 characters of `$1` and continuing until `$1` is empty.

Then use the parsing trick to assign the result from `$2` to `%2`

Comment: IMO using `$` as a leading part of a batch variable name only leads to confusion to people having a background with multiple script languages albeit this is valid - smells like a try to obfuscate.

Comment: @LotPings: I agree with you. IMHO the only result of use `$1` and `$2` as variable names in a Batch file is confuse people, particularly the beginners, with not a single real advantage...

Answer (score 0):

Another spin (just for fun)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sValue=CVDF1234"
set /a i=0, i1=1, i2=2
:lp
if not "!sValue:~%i1%!"=="" (
  set sValue=!sValue:~0,%i%!!sValue:~%i1%,1!!sValue:~%i%,1!!sValue:~%i2%!
  set /a i+=2, i1+=2, i2+=2
  goto lp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "sValue=CVDF1234"
set "newsValue="

:loop
   set "newsValue=%newsValue%%sValue:~1,1%%sValue:~0,1%"
   set "sValue=%sValue:~2%"
if defined sValue goto loop

echo %newsValue%
```

If the number of character pairs is fixed (4 in this example), the method may run faster in this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "sValue=CVDF1234"
set "newsValue="

for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do (
   set "newsValue=!newsValue!!sValue:~1,1!!sValue:~0,1!"
   set "sValue=!sValue:~2!"
)

echo %newsValue%
```

I invite you to compare the timing of this method vs. the PowerShell one...